# PHP call to static function fails

Tags: php, static

All,

I'm getting an error with the code below.  Here is the error message I get:
`Notice: Undefined variable: userDAO in C:\wamp\www\Projetv0.2\Model_User.php on line 15`
and then
`Fatal error: Call to a member function checkRecordExists() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Projetv0.2\Model_User.php on line 15`

The relevant code is below.  What I try to do with the code is have a unique class (`DAO_DBrecord`) to access several tables in a db.  In the case below, I want to access my `users` table.  To do that I have created a specific static function `createUserDAO` inside the `DAO_DBrecord` class that calls the constructor with the right table name, `users`.  However, it doesn't work, and I can't figure why.

Model_User.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('Class_DB.php');
    require_once('DAO_DBrecord.php');

    class Model_user{ // Represents a connection to the users table in the DB
        private $db;
        private $userDAO;

        function __construct($db){
            $this->db=$db;
            $userDAO=DAO_DBrecord::createUserDAO($this->db);//  static function - calls constructor w/ 'user' table name parameter
            $this->userDAO=$userDAO;
        }
        function userInfoExists($userInfo, $colName){
            return $userDAO->checkRecordExists($userInfo, $colName);
        }
//Other stuff
    }
?>
```

DAO_DBrecord.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('Class_DB.php');

    class DAO_DBrecord {
        private $db;
        private $table;

        private function __construct($db,$table){
            $this->db=$db;
            $this->table=$table;
        }

        public static function createUserDAO($db) {
            return new DAO_DBrecord($db, 'users');
        }
//Other stuff
    }
?>
```

Thank you all for your help!

JDelage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a problem with the static function.  The problem is that PHP doesn't have an implicit `$this`.  When you're referring to the member variable within the class (as you are in `userInfoExists`), you have to say `$this->userDAO` rather than just `$userDAO`.

Of course, all this assumes that the `DAO_DBrecord` class has or inherits a `checkRecordExists` function.  If it doesn't, you're going to have other problems.

Comment: Doh...  Thank you. It's always the dumbest mistakes that get me.